# Android Date timezone issues

Tags: java, android, date, timezone

a). I have 3 strings representing the date, time and timeZone; ex.:

```
String date = "2012-09-04";
String time = "01:30:17";
String timeZone = "UTC";
```

and I want to create a date using these strings.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
Date createdDate = formatter.parse(date + " " + time + " " + timeZone);
```

doesn't work - I get the message "Unparseable date".

b). How can I get the Android device date in a specific timeZone?
I found just a way of converting current time to, for example, UTC timeZone:

```
Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateInUTCTimeZone = sdf.format(cldr.getTime());
```

but I want the result to be a Date object.

Comment: This isn't android specific. Have you tried googling for 'Java timezones' or similar?

Comment: instaed of appending it while parse make string outside and than try that whole string to parse

Answer (score 3):

The string "UTC" is nothing that the Date parser can recognize. If you need to use this constant for defining UTC, then the following date format should work for you

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'");
```

but I'd strongly recommend tu use the rfc3990 standard:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

and then represent your date as the following string (2012-09-04T13:24:59Z).

Finally if you want to represent a date which is in UTC to a certain time zone, use the following before formatting:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); //Choose the TimeZone you need
```